# AJAX cropping not working in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, image, codeigniter

I am making a Code Igniter site and am trying to implement ajax crop of profile image from http://croppic.net/

URL:http://myphpdevelopers.com/dev/selfee_social/
user: notype@yopmail.com
passwd: abcd1234

dashboard URL: http://myphpdevelopers.com/dev/selfee_social/notype.

hover over the profile pic in the upper left part of the page. An icon will be visible which will invoke a file uploader on clicking.

on choosing an image in uploader, a file crop overlay should be displayed.
However, the loader keeps spinning and shows no ovderlay.

If you inspect the page in developer console in say, firefox you will see a number of errors:-

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  chown(): Operation not permitted</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/home.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 292</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  mkdir(): Permission denied</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/myfile_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 11</p>

 </div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  mkdir(): Permission denied</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/myfile_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 11</p>

</div>The upload path does not appear to be valid.
```

The upload path is `/home/myphpdev/public_html/dev/selfee_social/user_photos/profile` but I guess its not writable so I wrote the following code in my controller

```
public function ajax_upload_profile_pic()
    {
        //error reporting

        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set("display_errors", "On");

        header("Content-Type:application/json;");
        $ua = $this->session->userdata('user_auth');

        $uniq_id = $ua["id"];

        if(empty($ua))
        {
            die("not authenticated");
        }

        if($_FILES['img']['error']==0)
        {
            $owner = @exec('whoami');
            $DIR = $this->profile_image_path;

            chown($DIR, $owner);
            //chmod($DIR, 0755);
            $temp_path = $DIR. 'temp/'. $uniq_id.'/';

            if (!file_exists($temp_path)){
                my_create_dirs_r($temp_path, 0777);
            }

             $config = array(
                    'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
                    'upload_path' => $temp_path,
                     'max_size' => 0
                    );
             //$this->load->library('upload', $config);//not working

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('img'))
            {
                echo $this->upload->display_errors('','');die();
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error',$this->upload->display_errors('',''));

            }   
            else
            {   
                $image_data = $this->upload->data("");

            }

            $response = array(
                "status" => 'success',
                "url" => base_url('user_photos/profile/temp/' . $uniq_id . '/' . $image_data['file_name']),
                        'file' => $image_data['file_name'],
                "width" => $image_data['image_width'],
                "height" => $image_data['image_height']
            );
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        //echo json_encode($ua);

        die();
    }
```

the image file is not getting uploaded and the overlay to crop it is not displayed

The profile image path is

```
$this->profile_image_path = realpath('.').'/user_photos/profile/';
```

and the helper `myfile_helper.php` has the function below:

```
if ( ! function_exists('my_create_dirs_r'))
{
    function my_create_dirs_r($dirName, $rights=0777){
        $dirs = explode('/', $dirName);
        $dir='';
        foreach ($dirs as $part) {
            $dir.=$part.'/';
            if (!is_dir($dir) && strlen($dir)>0)
                mkdir($dir, $rights);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

- the web directory is owned by the apache user. ("ls -al" will tell
  you)
- the parent directory in which you want to create is also owned by
  this user.
- the parent directory isn't a mount in which you don't have write
  permissions
- the path you want to create is correct (var_dump($dstDir) will tell
  you)
     $this->newDirMode is contains a correct permission value. (If you are running on windows this will be ignored)

If there is no problem and it still doesn't work I would do:

- make yourself the apache user and try to create it manually ("sudo -u
  apache" if your username is apache)
- try to omit the third parameter 'true' in
  "mkdir($dstDir,$this->newDirMode,true);" and create all directories
  one after another
- inspect the logs ("/var/log/apache" is your friend)

Hope this helps.